# mac hosts file - only home URL works

Tags: macos, local, host

I have my hosts file set up on my mac

```
127.0.0.1       my.localsite.com
127.0.0.1       my2.localsite.com
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1       more.localsite.com
127.0.0.1       more2.localsite.com
```

and when I go to http://my.localsite.com:8080, the home page of the site I am working on displays correctly.  When I go to another link of the site, for example my.localsite.com:8080/page1 or my.localsite.com:8080/page2 my browser tells me the site can't be found.  I have added the my and my2.localsite.com to the top of the hosts file and that did not make a difference.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost my.localsite.com my2.localsite.com more.localsite.com more2.localsite.com
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

If it's not a problem with the `hosts` file and it seems so (see comments below) then it might do with the web server's virtual hosts configuration. You didn't mention what server you're using, so I can't give a specific answer. Let's take Apache as an example.
It can be [configured to serve different sites based on the hostname](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

So, the conclusion is: check your web server virtual hosts configuration.

Comment: I tried doing this and initially thought it worked, but realized that one of my settings was incorrect in the local site I was using.  I am still only able to get the home page to work.  All other site links come up as page not found.

Comment: Ok, so it's not a problem with `hosts`. Maybe it's the virtual hosts configuration - see updated answer above.